# How can I write Ruby unit tests for class definitions and so on?

Tags: ruby

Some of the key features in a library I'm writing revolve around what happens when you subclass some of the classes it provides.

I try to write unit tests before writing any actual code whenever I'm implementing a new feature. However, a lot of what I need to do is this sort of thing:

```
class Hand < FancyDocument
    push_to $handDB
end 
class Foot < FancyDocument
    push_to $footDB
end
```

One of the things I want to test is whether that class method works in the first place, before having methods that test whether instances of the class behave properly.

But in Ruby you can't define classes inside methods, so I don't know how to test this. I can just put them inside my test class and watch for whether an error is thrown, but this is not very elegant and throws away many of the advantages of using a proper test framework. And if I introduce some other code in the future that breaks this, it'll be less obvious exactly what broke and why.

Is there a way around this problem? Should I be using something other than the standard Test/Unit library?

Comment: Is there any implementation in your base classes that you are creating?  Do you provide some sort of code that accepts instances of those base classes and does things to those instances?  Off the cuff, it sounds like you are trying to write unit tests for abstract base classes.  You can't unit test something that is abstract.  You can only test concrete things that use that abstraction (e.g. related classes that accept the abstract base class, or derived concrete classes).

Comment: A mock object library is often used to solve the "I can't create a class inside a unit test method" problem.  I don't know ruby though, so I can't tell you if you need such a library (or if such a library exists), or if you can use built in features to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: A mock object framework only serves to help test interactions between distinct components... it doesn't really solve the problem of testing an abstract base class. In all languages I've used, you'd usually just define a subclass in the test, albeit a concrete subclass. Ruby makes it possible to create a temporary class that is discarded when the test ends, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't define a class within a method? Of course you can! This is Ruby we're talking about!

```
class FancyDocument
end

def define_a_class
  Class.new(FancyDocument)
end

klass = define_a_class
klass.ancestors # => => [#<Class:0x10151fd90>, FancyDocument, Object, Kernel]
```

The only thing that's hard to define within a method are constants.

**Edit:** You can use `const_set(string, value)` to define a constant, and therefore make it a non-anonymous class. I'm not sure whether it's a good idea though.

Comment: This is enlightening, but is it possible to define a non-anonymous class? There are behaviours that depend upon the name of the class itself.

Comment: @Cerales: Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Cerales: All classes are anonymous in Ruby. There's nothing special about the `String` class, for example. It's just an anonymous class that happens to have been assigned to the variable `String`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: `String` is a constant, not a variable (unless you're saying constants are a kind of variable). Not that constants are very constant in Ruby!

Comment: I usually consider constants as a kind of variable, just like local variables, block local variables, instance variables, class hierarchy variables, global variables, magic global variables, thread-local magic global variables, pseudo variables and whatever else Ruby has. As you say, they are "variable" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I use RSpec, but the following would apply to any test framework.  When I'm testing an abstract class, I try to isolate it as much as possible (and keep my fixtures clear), so I tend to create an anonymous subclass from it:

```
let(:document) { Class.new(FancyDocument) }
```

`Class.new` accepts a block if you need to add specific implementation to your fixture.